# Unable to use File.tempfile in crystal lang - undefined reference to `*Crystal::System::Dir::tempdir:String'

Tags: crystal-lang, temp

I am trying to create a temp file using below code

```
tmp_file = File.tempfile("upload")
```

but not able to compile it , getting below errors

```
D-ir.o: In function `tempdir':
/usr/share/crystal/src/dir.cr:168: undefined reference to `*Crystal::System::Dir::tempdir:String'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Please help me to solve it.

## Update 1

This is happening in v -

```
Crystal 0.33.0 [612825a53] (2020-02-14)

LLVM: 8.0.0

Default target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this error.

Maybe it's a cache issue. Try removing Crystal's cache dir: `rm -rf $(crystal env CRYSTAL_CACHE_DIR)`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce either (Arch Linux, Crystal 0.33.0). Do you get the error in a bigger program, or can you reproduce with a file that only has that one line?

Comment: not sure what happened but it started working automatically. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this was not reproducible by others & it was fixed automatically for me - i am answering this question.

I have tried multiple times to compile but it didn't work, so  i have commented out the piece of code & keep working on others changes. Today i tried again after seeing some comments and it was fixed. I am really not sure what happened.

If you are experiencing this - Please do a restart of your computer.

Hope this helps other people.

Comment: Possibly corrupted `Dir-o.o` file or something weird like that...